# How can I reorganize my return in an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

let's say I've got a function where I'm fetching for some data from a DB.

```
findById(id) {
    return Model.findById(id)
}
```

I need to reorganize the return from the `user data` like this:

```
{
   name: "Tom",
   age: 57
}
```

into something like this:

```
{
   message: "User is found successfully", 
   success: true, 
   user: user
}
```

So far I can manage with that with a `Promise "then"` section, like this:

```
return Model.findById(id)
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          logger.warn(`Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`);
          return { message: `Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`, success: false, user: null };
        }
        return { message: `User with id: ${id}`, success: true, user: user };
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err.message);
          return { message: err.message, success: false, user: null };
        }
      })
```

Can I do the same with a `async/await` and return my reorninazed return? 
Because so far it returns the `user object` from the DB:

```
async findById(id) {

    return await this.model.findById(id, function (user, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('test');
        logger.error(err);
        return { message: err.message, success: false, user: null };
      }
      if (!user) {
        logger.warn(`Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`);
        return { message: `Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`, success: false, user: null };
      }
      return { message: `User with id: ${id}`, success: true, user: user };
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most database APIs do NOT support both a callback and a promise at the same time.  If you pass a callback, they do not return a promise.  Pick one style or the other.  Your first approach using `.then()` works just fine as that is all promise-based.

Your second approach does not work because you're passing a regular callback.  That tells the database to NOT return a promise because you're using the older callback style, but you're trying to use that promise.

If you want to use `async/await`, you could do so like this:

```
async findById(id) {
    try {
        let user = await this.model.findById(id);
        if (user) {
            return { message: `User with id: ${id}`, success: true, user: user };
        } else {
            logger.warn(`Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`);
            return { message: `Coundn't find user with id: ${id}`, success: false, user: null };
        }
    } catch(e) {
        logger.error(err);
        return { message: err.message, success: false, user: null };
    }
}
```

FYI, you can remove the `if (err)` test in the `.catch()` handler from your first code block.  If `.catch()` is triggered, there is an error - you don't need to test if one is there.